# Передача русских символов в качестве аргументов java

Tags: java, кодировка

При вызове java-программы из командной строки с аргументами в качестве русских символов эти аргументы не распознаются программой. Что можно сделать, чтобы этого избежать?

Код программы:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(args[0]);
        System.out.println("Тест 2");
    }
}
```

Код запуска (bat файл):

```
chcp 65001
java -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Dconsole.encoding=UTF-8 -jar "Best program.jar" "Привет мир2"
```

В итоге вывод:

```
?????? ???2
Тест 2
```

UPD: решение проблемы не нашёл, в итоге запускаю программу на сервере(Linux) через php-скрипт, так программа нормально работает с аргументами:

```
exec('java -jar "Best program.jar" "Привет мир2"');
```

Answer (score 1):

У вас, скорее всего, `.bat` файл сохранен в кодировке `cp1251`, перекодируйте его в `UTF-8`, всё должно заработать.

Comment: Пробовал, не помогло(

Answer (score 0):

Манипуляции с кодировкой консоли и JVM не нужны. Просто

```
> javac -encoding utf-8 Test.java
> java Test "Привет мир"
```

Естественно, кодировка Test.java должна соответствовать значению ключа `encoding`.

Comment: Работает, но как быть с .jar файлами?

Comment: Для них ничего не меняется. Просто добавляется этап упаковки.

Comment: Сейчас заметил, что ваше решение работает только на моей второй системе, работающей на Linux (там и без ключа всё отлично работает). На windows как было так и осталось(

Comment: @Obroten54 https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mzlmr.png

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/b0ORZLR.png - всё же зависит от настроек ОС...

Comment: @Obroten54 у вас файл Test.java точно в кодировке utf-8?

Comment: @Obroten54 какие-либо настройки операционной системы, связанные с кодировкой, меняли? Мой вариант работает на чистой Windows любой версии, установленной с настройками по умолчанию.

Comment: Да, в кодировке utf-8. Windows на английском, может в этом проблема.

Comment: У меня есть английская виртуалка. На ней проблема не наблюдается.